# Viewing bash history of separate active TTY

Tags: shell, tty, command-history, proc

I am working on a script that will help the sysadmins on our team monitor what's going on in other terminals by other logged in users.

One thing I'm stuck on right now is how to view what commands have been typed. I realize that the history doesn't get saved until the user exits or types `history -a`, but there has to be a way to view what's *currently* in the history, even if it's stored in memory somewhere.

Is it possibly saved somewhere in `/proc/${pid_of_users_bash}`? I tried to type a command echoing a unique string (EG: `echo "foobarbaz"`, then greping for *foobarbaz*  through any flat files within the associated `/proc/PID` directory, but no luck.

If anyone has a solution that doesn't involve setting the`PROMPT_COMMAND` or setting the `histappend` (like [these](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2007/11/keeping-command-history-across-multiple.html)), that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Christopher That's what happens on one of the systems I'm using. I'm _promptly_ unsetting `PROMPT_COMMAND` when logging in there. It also messes with `set -x` which I have turned on by default...

Answer (score 1):

Bash does not provide information you want. I think you want avoid setting `COMMAND_PROMPT` and `histappend` because users may easily overwrites them. But users may completely disable storing commands to history when they set `HISTCONTROL="ignorespace"` and insert a space before each command. So users that are not willing to be monitored cannot be reliably monitored via bash history.

Ad hoc monitoring a single session can be done over `strace`. Search for the PID of the user's bash and then call `strace -p <bash-pid> 2>&1 |grep "read(0,"`. The you can see all characters typed by user - including typos and editing commands.

Most of linux distribution provides `auditd` package. It monitors and audits system components so administrator may get information about system activities in past. A PAM module `pam_tty_audit` cooperates with `auditd` and  enables or disables TTY activity auditing. I guess you do not need to reinvent wheel and use the `pam_tty_audit`.